# React how to output name in iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, react-redux

I get the name of the movie in React, everything looks great

## {movie.name} / {movie.enname} ({years})

## h1 (Knives Out / Knives Out (2019)) /h1

. But
I can’t display this name in the iframe window in https://example.com/movie/{movie.name} Here is the iframe:

```html
<iframe src="https://example.com/movie/?imdb={movie.name}&notitle=1&cover=11" alt="{movie.imdb_id}" allowfullscreen width="50%" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

So it remains {movie.name} and {movie.imdb_id}, instead of the received name Knives Out. 
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the variable name is considered as a string in your iframe src

use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Example

```
<iframe src={`https://example.com/movie/?imdb=${movie.name}&notitle=1&cover=11`} alt={movie.imdb_id} allowfullscreen width="50%" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

or

```
<iframe src={"https://example.com/movie/?imdb="+movie.name+"&notitle=1&cover=11" } alt={movie.imdb_id} allowfullscreen width="50%" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```